# JPA Outbound Gateway - dynamic jpa-query resolution

Tags: spring-integration

I want to configure only one instance of JPA Outbound Gateway and want the jpa-query attribute to be dynamically resolved at runtime by the underlying JPAExecutor instance. Can anyone please let me know if this is possible ? If possible can you please provide an example ? I looked at the spring samples but the examples have hard-coded query in the jpa-query attribute of the JPA outbound gateway. (P.S. The HTTP Oubound gateway has similar concepts for url / uri variables resolution.)

This is something what I am looking for:

```
<int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"
    request-channel="listPeopleRequestChannel" 
    jpa-query="{queryString}"> </int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway>
```

where `queryString = "select p from Person p order by p.name asc"`

Answer (score 1):

Until the issue will be resolved, there is some workaround for you.

As you noticed, the  `<int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway>` supports `jpa-operations` injection, as well as other SI JPA components.

So, you always can implement your own one with appropriate logic for the `poll(final Message<?> requestMessage)` method to determine the `query` at runtime against `requestMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic query string is not currently supported. Feel free to open up a new feature [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) to add an expression-based query that will be resolved at runtime for each message.